# How to implement version control in Access 2003?

Tags: ms-access

I have a Access 2003 DB that I need to fix and the previous developer did not use any form of version control and the notes on his code are weak or non-existent.  What is a good way to implement version control with Access 2003?

Comment: This has come up before: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bms-access%5D+version+control

Comment: Check out this article on how to version control a Access DB: http://kb.dynamsoft.com/questions/155/How+to+integrate+SourceAnywhere+Standalone+with+MS+Access%3F

Answer (score 0):

Access is fully compatible with any provider that implements the Microsoft Source Code Control Interface (MSSCCI).  So you can use VSS, or even to my knowledge Team Foundation Server.

Note that using SCC with Access does resolve down to the object level. So check in/out of single query, single form, single form etc. is not only possible, but then thus gives rise to allow more than one developer to work on the project.

Access 2003 is rather old now (10 years).  Later editions of Access include the source code control option without the need for any add-in or download. The older versions of Access do require a download + installing of SCC support.

However, SCC been built into the product – since the 90's, so it is a long time feature that been around over 15+ years for use with Access. Note that even in Access 2003 such as this screen shot shows - the Access UI does have built in support and you can sell see what objects are checked out:

[image]

(note the check box in above)
And here is another view – again the check box shows items I have checked out from the project, and the "lock" shows other objects I not yet taken.

[image]

The SCC link I have for 2003 is here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837136/en-us